# Get the php template file from other theme folder

Tags: php, templates, get-template-part

How to get the php template file from other theme folder?

---

For Example :

My Current Theme Folder is `promax` . Im working on `archive.php` and want to include a template file inside of `archive.php` from other folder called child theme `promax-child'`  and a folder inside called `includes` has a file `archive-desc.php`.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the template with the [`template_include`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include//get_template_directory/) filter. This example will filter the archive template for all archive pages. If you need to do this for a specific archive, use [`is_post_type_archive( $post_types )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive) as your condition. Put this in your `functions.php` file of your child theme.

```
function my_archive_filter( $template) {
    if ( is_archive() ) {
        return 'path/to/includes/archive-desc.php'; // Path to your child theme template.
    }
    else {
        return $template;
    }
}

apply_filters( 'template_include', 'my_archive_filter' );
```

Edit: It should now fall back to the default template if the custom template fails for some reason.